# Azure App Service Migration Assistant keeps crashing

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I am trying to use the Azure App Service Migration Assistant to migrate a web app to Azure.  I am not a developer so not sure what type of web app it is but it does connect to a SQL database.  The web app is running on IIS on a Windows 2012 R2 server and the database is running on a separate Windows 2012 R2 server on SQL 2014.  I installed the Azure App Service Migration Assistant on the web server but each time I try to run it, it generates a pop-up that says "Web Deploy is needed for migrating your site content and database to azure".  When I click Yes to install it, it generates the error in the image below:

[Web_Deploy_Install_Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Oneg.jpg)

Comment: When you get that error, if you click Ctrl-C, it should put the content in the clipboard, which you can them paste here (easier to consume than screenshot).

Comment: Tried that but it would not let me do it.  Basically...I tried CTRL-V as well as right-click and paste...but neither did anything.

Comment: Is it related to https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Websites-Migration-Tool/issues/7? This one seems to related to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/web/webpi/5.0/webproductlist.xml being down. Not sure what the deal is with that endpoint. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/web/webpi/5.0/webproductlist.xml is up.

Comment: @david-ebbo I think it is the tool because when I ran web deploy from the command line, everything worked fine and the item the tool said it needed to install was already installed.  I got around it by clicking no to install the product.  I went thru the process of migrating my website which it did successfully but really in the end all it did was create a new App Service and App Service Plan in my subscription.  It did not migrate any of the content or the database.  Yet it did not give me any errors.

Comment: Chatting with the team that owns Azure App Service Migration Assistant, the tool is no longer supported, and they are going to update the page to reflect that.

Comment: @DavidEbbothanks for the info...I figured as much when I noticed how long it has been since anyone has touched the repo in GitHub.  Is there a replacement for it?

Comment: It sounds like there will be, but timeframe is unclear. Sorry, I'm only getting second hand info here, so I don't have a great answer for you!